# glDrawArrays and glVertexAttribPointer

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, rendering

I'm trying to learn OpenGL and GLSL. I'm trying to draw an imported model, which is stored in three arrays (vertices - `array of TVector3`, which is a record/struct with X, Y, Z: single/float; normals - `array of TVector3`; UVs - `array of TVector2`). The model was drawn fine without using shaders and using old calls such as `glTexCoord`, `glNormal` and `glVertex`. I switched to `glDrawArrays` because everything is always deprecated and trying to use shaders and `glTexCoordPointer` didn't work as the `layout (location = 2)` contained either incorrect UV mapping or none at all (texture is still there because the mesh is given coloring) and `glTexCoordPointer` didn't affect it at all. However, when trying to use the `glVertexAttribPointer` approach found on [this tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/4.2.textures_combined/textures_combined.cpp) nothing is drawn at all. I convert the three arrays into one `array of single`, but still to no avail. Trying to use `glDrawElements` results in a SIGSEGV, because I have no indices to provide (also I've read it's slower than glDrawArrays).

I'm lost, is there anything I'm doing wrong? Maybe I'm missing something? Are there any ways to pass arrays of TVectorX without combining them all into one?

My code (Object Pascal, OpenGL 4.3):

```
type
  TVector2 = record
    public
      X, Y: single;
      {...}
  end;  
  TVector3 = record
    private                                     
      {...}
    public
      X, Y, Z: single; 
      {...}
  end;

var
  MeshArray: array of single;  
  VertexArray, VertexBuffer: longword;    

{Mesh initialization code:}

SetLength(MeshArray, Length(Vertices)*8);
for i:=1 to Length(Vertices) do begin
  j := (i-1)*8;
  MeshArray[ j ] := Vertices[i-1].X;
  MeshArray[j+1] := Vertices[i-1].Y;
  MeshArray[j+2] := Vertices[i-1].Z;
  MeshArray[j+3] := Normals[i-1].X;
  MeshArray[j+4] := Normals[i-1].Y;
  MeshArray[j+5] := Normals[i-1].Z;
  MeshArray[j+6] := UVs[i-1].X;
  MeshArray[j+7] := UVs[i-1].Y;
end;
glGenVertexArrays(1, @VertexArray);
glGenBuffers(1, @VertexBuffer);

glBindVertexArray(VertexArray);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, SizeOf(MeshArray), @MeshArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, SizeOf(single) * 8, PChar(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, SizeOf(single) * 8, PChar(3 * SizeOf(single)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, SizeOf(single) * 8, PChar(6 * SizeOf(single)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);  

{Drawing code:}

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);  //Not necessary
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mat.Albedo.Data); 

glUseProgram(mat.ShaderProgram);
//Draws model correctly, but without UV when using glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, @Vertices[0]);

glBindVertexArray(VertexArray);      
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, Length(Vertices));
```

Vertex shader (MatVertex is just the object and camera matrix):

```
#version 430 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 Vertex;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 Normal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 UV;

out vec3 outVertex;
out vec3 outNormal;
out vec2 outUV;

uniform mat4 MatVertex;

void main(){
    gl_Position = vec4(Vertex, 1.0) * MatVertex;
    outVertex = Vertex;
    outNormal = Normal;
    outUV = UV;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 430 core

in vec3 outVertex;
in vec3 outNormal;
in vec2 outUV;

out vec3 color;

uniform sampler2D albedoTex;

void main(){
    color = texture(albedoTex, outUV).rgb;
}
```

[image]

Comment: so this code draws nothing at all? Are you sure that MatVertex has the right matrix in it? You didn't show that you are giving a value to MatVertex.

Comment: @user253751 The image on the left uses the exact same shader with MatVertex supplied.

Comment: Oh so it does render something. But the texture is not applied. I assume that if you set `color = vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);` it renders red?

Comment: The left picture is labeled glVertexPointer,glTexCoordPointer,glNormalPointer which are not how you supply data to shaders - so I assumed this was not the picture with the shader

Comment: As a side note: the reason all the non-shader stuff is deprecated is that *shaders are so much simpler* when you get your head around them. Yeah, you have to write a shader, but all these functions like glNormalPointer go away, and there's just a few functions that send data to shader variables, and the variables can be whatever you want them to be, and there's no hidden behind-the-scenes magic about certain variables.

Comment: @user253751 `glVertexPointer,glTexCoordPointer,glNormalPointer` are there to indicate that the render in the image uses them, instead of `glVertexAttribPointer`. Setting the color to a fixed vec3 with `glVertexAttribPointer` changes nothing.

Comment: so you already rendered the grey cube without the shader, and the shader is rendering nothing?

Comment: @user253751 That's what I said, just to clarify the model is being imported correctly. The shader renders when I use `glVertexPointer` etc. instead of `glVertexAttribPointer`. When I use `glVertexAttribPointer` nothing is being rendered.

Answer (score 1):

The vector needs to be multiplied to the matrix from the tight (see [GLSL Programming/Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations)):

<s>`gl_Position = vec4(Vertex, 1.0) * MatVertex;`</s>

```c
gl_Position = MatVertex * vec4(Vertex, 1.0);
```

Comment: When rendering with `glVertexPointer` (to render anything at all) this results in incorrect projection. The image on the left is rendered with the aforementioned shader and vertex/position-wise is rendered as wanted. Modifying this line in the shader and using `glVertexAttribPointer` provides no change at all.

Comment: @GreatCorn I have no idea what you're trying to tell me. `glVertexPointer` set the fixed function attributes. The fixed function vertices are transformed the fixed function pipeline matrices. Now you have to do the matrix transformation in the shader. This transformation seems to be wrong and the projection matrix seems to is missing.

Comment: The shader received model vertex data in `layout (location = 0) in vec3 Vertex;` when using `glVertexPointer`. I'm trying to switch to `glVertexAttribPointer`, which is in the provided code, but I can't get it to work. MatVertex is a perspective matrix multiplied by the camera TRS matrix in the code. It displayed the model and transformations correctly when I wasn't using `glVertexAttribPointer` and the initialization code.

Comment: @GreatCorn Yes I understand that. However, since the vertex attribute setup looks correct to me, I suspect the matrices are wrong.

Comment: Passing the matrices to the shader and multiplying them there did not work either. If they worked with the semi-fixed function approach, I don't see why this would produce different transformation results.

Comment: @GreatCorn The value set by glVertexPointer would be the built-in variable gl_Vertex. Not your own variable called Vertex.

Comment: @GreatCorn It's a bad idea to mix the fixed function pipeline with the programmable pipeline.

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget I'm not. I'm trying to switch and used the fixed function pipeline just to show the matrix transformations worked and the model was imported correctly.